# How to mounts a directory from container into the host

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I create a deployment yaml for a microservice.
I am using `hostpath` volume type for `persistentVolume` and I have to copy data to a path in host. But I want to mount a directory from container into the host because data is in the container and I need this data in host.

My deployment yaml:

```
#create persistent volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-vol
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /opt/storage/app

#create persistent volume clame
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: app-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
#create Deployment
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deploy: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: app
    spec:
      hostname: app
      hostNetwork: false
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: 192.168.10.10:2021/project/app:latest
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/app
              name: project-volume
      volumes:
        - name: project-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pv-claim
```

Comment: Why doesn't your container write that data to the mounted hostPath? If it does - the host already have the data.

Comment: after deployment If I create a new file in container , the data transfer to host. But when I create deployment I have to transfer manually the data to hostpath Until the service comes up

Comment: I build image and I expect that the data of container image (/opt/app) exist in hostpath , But  I have to transfer manually the data to hostPath Until the service comes up

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar. when I don't transfer data in hostpath this Error occur. but without persistent volume I don't have any problem.

Comment: Kubernetes is a distributed clustered environment; _which_ host should have the data?  What happens if the pod gets recreated on a different node?  I strongly suspect you don't want a `hostPath:` volume here; if the goal is to have the raw data on your local system and not out in the cluster somewhere, Kubernetes might not be the best match for your needs.

Comment: I run a image with docker, in docker I use volume and I define that what path mount to docker volume, now in kubernetes I want to setup it.

Comment: The data created by one pod should stay in `hostPath` directory so some other pod should have access as long as they are running on the same node. Could you check if both pods (the one that created the data and the second one that want to access the data) are on the same node - `kubectl get pods -o wide`? Could you provide more details about your docker volume setup - commands that you used?

Answer (score 0):

Due to information gaps, I am writing a general answer.

First of all you should know:

> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly.

But the use of `hostPath` also offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.

If you still want to use it, firstly you should check if both pods (the one that created the data and the second one that want to access the data) are on the same node. The following command will show you that.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

All data created by any of pods should stay in `hostPath` directory and be available for every pod as long as they are running on the same node.

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20details.-,hostPath,-Warning%3A) about hostPath.